# Socket disconnected unexpectedly while using angular

Tags: node.js, socket.io, angularjs-scope

```
<body>
<ul id="messages"></ul>
<form action="">
  <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button onclick="message()">Send</button>
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>  
var app = angular.module('groupChatApp', []);
  app.controller('groupChatController', function($scope) {
    var socket = io();
   $scope.message = function(event){
       event.preventDefault(); 
       var msg = document.getElementById("m").value;
       if(msg !== ""){
       socket.emit('chat message',msg);
       }
       document.getElementById("m").value="";
   } 
   socket.on('chat message',function(value){
       console.log(value);
       document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML += "<li>"+value+"</li>";
   })
  });    
</script>
```

This is my index.html page to design a group chat using socket.io

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    response.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
io.on('connection',function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');
    socket.on('chat message',function(msg){
        console.log('message: '+msg);
        io.emit('display',msg);
    });
    socket.on('disconnect',function(){
       console.log('user disconnected')
    })
});

http.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("listening on 3000");
});
```

This is my index.js file. The user is getting disconnected each time a message is sent. Working well with JS, not with angular. Any suggestions why this happened

Thanks in advance

Comment: make your message emit event `chatMessage` instead of `chat message`, I'm not sure that spaces are valid in socket's emit event names.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$scope.message = function(event)` has a parameter `event` and in your html code you have `<button onclick="message()">`.
Change the html to `<button onclick="message(event)">` and it will work